# Prevent AJAX call after inital AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I’ve been struggling to find the cause of this issue. I have user a form with the following (http://localhost/siteName/user/detail/123). I’m able to successfully update a section on this page via AJAX using the following code.

```
$("#userFormBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        if ($("#userForm").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/siteName/user/save", 
            data: $("#userForm").serialize(), 
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
            success: function(rData){
               if (rData.activity.success) {         
                    // DO STUFF…
               }else{
                    Alert(“error”);
               }
               //return false;
            }
         });
        return false;
     }
});
```

The problem is after the code above execute another AJAX get() runs calling the same page. In my case it call the current url (http://localhost/siteName/user/detail/123) again. I read many post regarding similar issues but none of the issues were like mine.  Can someone tell me what I’m missing? Thanks in advance!

Here’s what it looks like in fire bug.
[image]

Comment: your form button type is submit... replace type to button to prevent the second AJAX call

Comment: Hi ymz, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work, I'd already tried that. <form id="userForm">
 <!--- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>  ---> 
 <a href="javascript:;" id="userFormBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Submit</a>
</form>

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle or something to show your problem? Without the DOM it may be hard to diagnose

Comment: I found the issue is has to do with jquery smallbox plugin. It's adding a sound with every alert (http://localhost/sitename/assets/sound/smallbox.ogg). I wondering if change the relative path would fix this. Any suggestions?